# What do these JS shorthand characters mean?

Tags: javascript, regex, shorthand

I've been trying to find out what this code means but I haven't had any luck even finding out where to start or what to look up.

```
if(!/^(https?):\/\//i.test(value))
```

I understand some of it so I've got the following questions.

1. what does the "/^" do?
2. what does the ? do?
3. what do the "(" and ")" do around the https
4. what does the ":" do?
5. what does the "i" do?

If this appears to be a question without research, any guidance where to start would be great.

Comment: The characters all make up a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What is it

*A regular expression is an object that describes a pattern of characters.*

*Regular expressions are used to perform pattern-matching and "search-and-replace" functions on text.*

This is exactly the same but maybe more clear

```
var patt = /^(https?):\/\//i;
if( !patt.test(value) ){
  // value DOES NOT MATCH patt!
}
```

#### What it does

In this case it checks that `value` doesn't start with `http://` or `https://`

#### RegExp Explanation

```
  / //Open regexp
    ^ //Start of the string
    (  // Start of the capturing group
      https? //Match literally http or https (because s is optional "?")
    )  // End of capturing group
    :\/\/ // Match literally ://
  / // Close regexp
  i // Case-insensitive flag
```

#### Learning

- Starting point: [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/)
- Testing online with RegExp Explanation: [RegEx101](https://www.regex101.com/)

Comment: Down vote because of linking to W3Schools. A horrible resource for learning...

Comment: I've changed to RegexOne is better now?

Comment: Yeah, RegexOne or MDN are much better.

Answer (score 1):

Might this help you

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `http` matches the characters http literally (case insensitive)
- `s?` matches the character s literally (case insensitive)
- Quantifier: `?` Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `:` matches the character : literally
- `\/` matches the character / literally
- `i` modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])